# Should there be 'total derivative' symbol in the mathematical representation of back-propagation algorithm's formula?

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation, mathematics

I curiously want to know why in many references <sup>**[1][2]**</sup> on back propagation, authors use the *partial derivative* symbol, i.e $\frac{\partial}{\partial W}$, instead of correctly alternating between it and *total derivative symbol*, i.e $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{dW}}$?

Doesn't it make the back-propagation formula's derivation context more ambiguous?

[1]: Wikipedia - Back propagation - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation

[2]: Stanford Wiki - UFLDL- http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Backpropagation_Algorithm